# a sequence fn(x), prove that for each n, the integral of all fn(x) are 1/2

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$
> \text{Define f:}\left[ \text{0,}1 \right] \,\,\text{to }\left[ \text{0,}1 \right] \,\,\text{by:}
> \\
> \text{f}\left( \text{x} \right) =\begin{cases}
>  \text{2x, }0\leqslant \text{x}\leqslant \frac{1}{2}\\
>  -\text{2x}+\text{2, }\frac{1}{2}<\text{x}\leqslant 1\\
> \end{cases}
> \\
> \text{Next, define a sequence f}_{\text{n}}\,\,\text{of functions from }\left[ \text{0,}1 \right] \,\,\text{to }\left[ \text{0,}1 \right] \,\,\text{as follows:}
> \\
> \text{Let f}_1\left( \text{x} \right) =\text{f}\left( \text{x} \right) \,\,\text{and let f}_{\text{n}}\left( \text{x} \right) =\text{f}\left( \text{f}_{\text{n}-1}\left( \text{x} \right) \right) \,\,\text{for n}>\text{1. Prove that for each n,}
> \\
> \int\limits_0^1{\text{f}_{\text{n}}\left( \text{x} \right) \text{dx}=\frac{1}{2}}
> $$

This is a question from *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving*. Should I use the graph to interpret the results, or using some tricks in calculus?

Comment: What have you tried? Does $f_n$ have a certain form that you can figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you some intuition, draw some of the functions.

$f_{1}(x)$

[image]

$f_{2}(x)$

[image]

Try drawing $f_{3}(x)$. You get the pattern? You will also see that the integrations are all equal to $1/2$.

Once you do that I think you can use mathematical induction to finish the proof.